# .NET Threading - Quick question

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What should I put instead of the "SomeType" in the below function? 
Delegate seems to be wrong here..

```
 public static void StartThread(SomeType target)
 {
     ThreadStart tstart = new ThreadStart(target);
     Thread thread = new Thread(tstart);
     thread.Start();
 }
```

EDIT: I'm not looking for alternative ways to write this.

Comment: What do you mean you're not looking for alternative ways to write this?  Unless "SomeType" is defined as `delegate void SomeType()` you're going to have to.

Comment: I mean I just want to know what that SomeType should be. Other than that starting a thread could be written in many ways ofcourse.

Comment: Literally, SomeType should be what I just said, a delegate representing `void SomeType()` (or just System.Action, or, of course, ThreadStart).

Comment: System.Action is right. But ThreadStart is not. In the above concept, It would result in: ThreadStart tstart = new ThreadStart(new ThreadStart(sometarget));.. wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [System.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) type.

Here my test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartThread(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void StartThread(Action target)
{
    ThreadStart tstart = new ThreadStart(target);
    Thread thread = new Thread(tstart);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: You're answer isn't wrong, but isn't it more clear to use ThreadStart in this case, since that's what new Thread() takes?

Comment: I got what you mean. You are right. Actually, that is a better way if I rewrite the method. But the exact answer to my question seems to be System.Action.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `ThreadStart` as the argument instead of trying to initialize it within the method.

Comment: I could have but I want to know if it can be done like this. The ThreadStart takes arguments like this: ThreadStart(void () target).. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no Sometype, as you are calling some function that will be threaded. Isn't so?
Like
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(function_name_here));
t.start();

and 
void function_name_here()
{
Blah blah
}

FYI there is no return type but VOID.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `SomeType` with `System.Threading.ThreadStart` or `System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart`.